# amazon-like customer-seller mailing proxy

Tags: email, server, proxy

I have a website (mysite.com) hosted on a dedicated server.

I want to provide each user with an e-mail (address username@mysite.com) an alias for his/her original e-mail address (gmail, yahoo, etc.). Alias e-mail adressess will appear in messages as sender/receiver adresses while the original adresses are actually used to communicate.

### Example : It's some kind of email proxy service in both directions.

user1 : original = address1@gmail.com | alias = user1@mysite.com

user2 : original = address2@yahoo.com | alias = user2@mysite.com

Both of the users know the alias adress and not the original one.

address1@gmail.com emails user2@mysite.com => address2@yahoo.com receives the email with the sender set to user1@mysite.com. and vice-versa.

What are the solution existing allowing exchanging emails without having intermediate mailboxes, and with an automatic email address aliasing ? are there any known scripts for that ?

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance.